# Matlab: ylabel along y-axis

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm generating figures and I can't find the way to change the ylabel allignment so that it is along y-axis.

```
plot(tvals(:,1:dim), Values(:,1:dim))
title(Title)
xlabel(Xlabel)
ylabel(Ylabel')
```

[image]

Comment: Do not transpose your 'Ylabel'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do not transpose the `Ylabel`:

```
ylabel(Ylabel)
```

Compare output of the two lines

```
disp(Ylabel)
disp(Ylabel')
```

to see the difference

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to **rotate** the ylabel:

```
ylabel('something','rotation',90)
```